# ASP.NET MVC External login redirect URi from http to https

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, owin

I'm using the Microsoft.Owin in my MVC project.
After publishing the project to the server the redirect url for google and facebook are coming with [http], but my domain is [https].
I tried all the available solution online with no result.

false solution:
in web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"   redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

false solution:
in gloabal.asax

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest()
    If Not Context.Request.IsSecureConnection Then Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"))
End Sub
```

false solution:
in startup.auth

```
.OnApplyRedirect = Sub(context)
Dim redirectUri = New Uri(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute)
If redirectUri.Scheme = "http" And redirectUri.Host = context.Request.Uri.Host Then
context.RedirectUri = "https://xxxx/signin-google"
End If
End Sub
```

notes:

1. from my local machine the redirect URi is going as https
2. my server is under cloudflare CDN

Comment: You mean Google is redirecting to http URL of your application?

Comment: When I login with google signin it should redirect me to my domain which has https but instead it redirects me to my domain but starting with http

Comment: What's redirect url you have configured at Google?

Answer (score 1):

Your `web.config` solution has an error in it. In your condition, the pattern should be `off` or else it will only evaluate when the URL is already HTTPS. Like so.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"   redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```